# How can I automate supplying a version in appxmanifest?

Tags: wpf, msbuild, continuous-integration, desktop-bridge, appxmanifest

I am using the desktop bridge for a WPF desktop application and am looking to automate the creation of my msix packages during build. I do not want to store any version information in source control.

The WPF project in the solution uses the [gitversion](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/msbuild-task/#msbuild-task) msbuild task to automatically infer the version for my executable every time a build is done.
Unfortunately, I'm not sure if any such similar mechanism exists for `.appxmanifest`.

My thinking is that it would be nice to have this nicely integrated with the build process, similar to gitversion, but I haven't been able to find any documentation about what my options are during build or the *Create App Packages* process.

Perhaps there's some transform step during build that I'm not aware of that can be done to the `.appxmanifest`? Or maybe there's a way to have the version always reflect the version of the executable being bundled?

([MSDN forums question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92e5d7d9-2847-4f86-9821-5b15f7211ef9/how-can-i-automate-supplying-a-version-in-appxmanifest?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues))

Comment: If I use visual studio to generate package, it will automatically increase the version number. I'm not sure if the MSBuild do the same thing when you use it to generate package. I suggested to add 'msbuild' tag for your question.

Comment: Right, but of course incrementing the version implies that you're storing it in source control, which I don't want. Added msbuild, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to match the wpf version with the version in the  .appxmanifest file ?

Comment: Other way around.  I want the `.appxmanifest` to match my WPF version.

Answer (score 6):

Your should modify the `.appxmanifest` file in your build pipeline before you create the package. After all, it's just a text-based XML file.

If you are using Azure Pipelines, you could accomsplish this using a Powershell task and a counter variable that gets incremented for each build:

```yaml
    pool: 
      vmImage: vs2017-win2016
    variables:
      buildPlatform: 'x86'
      buildConfiguration: 'release'
      major: 1
      minor: 0
      build: 0
      revision: $[counter('rev', 0)]
    steps:
    - powershell: |
       [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Xml.Linq")
       $path = "Msix/Package.appxmanifest"
       $doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($path)
       $xName =
         [System.Xml.Linq.XName]
           "{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}Identity"
       $doc.Root.Element($xName).Attribute("Version").Value =
         "$(major).$(minor).$(build).$(revision)";
       $doc.Save($path)
      displayName: 'Version Package Manifest'
    +Build, Package and Sign.
```

Please refer to [this MSDN Magazine article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt833462) for more information and a complete example of how to set up continuous integration (CI), continuous deployment (CD) and automatic updates of sideloaded MSIX packaged WPF applications using Azure Pipelines.

Comment: I had to modify the `$xName =` line to `$xName = System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get(http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}Identity")`. Not sure if that's specific to my setup.

Answer (score 2):

You must update the manifest before packaging. Check out this sample including a powershell script to poke the xml with the gitversion provided. https://github.com/microsoft/devops-for-windows-apps/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml#L72